# How can I create a DataTemplate with Expression Blend 3?

Tags: data-binding, expression-blend

I'm currently experimenting with [Expression Blend 3 MIX09 version](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/try-it/blendpreview.aspx) with the idea to **use it primarily for an MVVM structured site with databinding, being able to view live data as I design**. So far I've been **very impressed** and have to say that **Blend 3's generated XAML is not as bad as people say it is**. I got the following two examples working, one with data binding and one with user controls (views) being loaded dynamically. I can stay in Expression Blend 90% of the time while I design my application, seeing live data coming from my ViewModels as I design. I switch to Visual Studio only for e.g. creating config files, or adding references is easier. The **improved intellisense of Blend 3** enabled me to stay in Blend for much of my coding as well:

- [MVVM base application that can be edited with Expression Blend and Visual Studio](http://tanguay.info/web/index.php?pg=codeExamples&id=168)
- [How to structure a WPF application with DataBinding so you can enhance it in Expression Blend](http://tanguay.info/web/index.php?pg=codeExamples&id=167)

One thing I'm surprised that I can't do in Expression Blend, though, is after I have created a ListBox, I would expect that I could do a right-click and **create a DataTemplate**. I can of course create a DataTemplate in code, then under Resources/Window I find it again, can click on a button next to it to "go into the DataTemplate" and see the controls inside in my Objects and Timeline panel, which is nice. But creating a DataTemplate from a control is so common, I would think there is a way to do it that I am just missing.

**Where in Blend 3 can you "create a DataTemplate" for a ListBox or ListView, etc?**

```
<UserControl
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestDynamic456"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Class="TestDynamic456.CustomersView"
    x:Name="UserControl"
    d:DesignWidth="640" d:DesignHeight="480">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <local:CustomersViewModel x:Key="CustomersDataProvider"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{x:Null}">

        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=GetAll, Source={StaticResource CustomersDataProvider}}"/>

    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 3):

In Blend 3, you create a DataTemplate for ItemsControl's in the same place where you do it in Blend2 ;)

Right Click the control->Edit Other Templates->Edit Generated Items(ItemTemplate)->CreateEmpty